# Want to convert 2d Matrix to the another 1d output in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

So I want to convert 2d 4*4 matrix into 1 d matrix with the two characteristics of the matrix.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1li0SIZapKHCYCO1EAr8YJMlGaZV-Uj8TRD3JgQUU_pI/edit?usp=sharing
This link should explain more.

The idea is that I want to pull data more than 100 from the matrix with column header and row header beside the data.

Could you please help me out. Prefer no script solution.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Note: [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code)

Comment: The file is not publicly available :-(

Comment: There is no code. I have changed the link to the public. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this way

```
=query(arrayformula(split(flatten(A2:A8&"|"&B1:G1&"|"&B2:G8),"|")),"select * where Col3 > 100")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the sheet for this?

Comment: I would like to re-use your spreadsheet but the access is denied!

Comment: Oh. I don't know why this happens. I have figured it out. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Try in H3 `=query(ArrayFormula(split(flatten(A2:A19&"|"&B1:E1&"|"&B2:E19),"|")),"select* where Col3>100 or Col3<-100")`